# RSA - Encrypting using only(!) Modulus?

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, .net-4.6, rsacryptoserviceprovider

We're using an API from another company .
In that API I should generate a key pair using `RSACryptoServiceProvider` and send  the public key so that they can encrypt data for us.

That's not a  problem. In their API - the public key is a `byte[]` type.

So I thought doing something like :

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
var pubKey = rsa.ToXmlString(false); //only public
```

And then ,  represent it as a `byte[]` :

```
var ValuetoSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pubKey);
```

And send that value.

But they responded :

> "You should only supply us the `Modulus` property in the `RSAKeyInfo` 
>   info"

So I've wondered , Is it possible ? Can they encrypt data only using Modulus ?

So I've created a test :  (please notice `My Code` and `Their code`)

```
   //My Code
    byte[] data_clear = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hellowא");
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
    var MyModulus = rsa.ExportParameters(true).Modulus;



    //Their code ( I assume , If they only want MyModulus)
    var rsa2 =   new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
    var rsa2Params = rsa2.ExportParameters(true);
    rsa2Params.Modulus=MyModulus;  //they set their Modulus to MY Modulus
    byte[] enc_data = rsa2.Encrypt(data_clear, true);

  // Back to my code


    var g=Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rsa.Decrypt(enc_data, true));
    Console.WriteLine(g);
```

Result :
Exception :

> CryptographicException  Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.

**Question**

1) Is it possible for them to encrypt using Modulus only?

2) If so  , What is wrong with my test and how can I fix it.

Edit - Even If I add the exponenet , it fails :

```
   //My Code
    byte[] data_clear = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("hellowא");
    var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
    var MyModulus = rsa.ExportParameters(true).Modulus;
    var MyExponent = rsa.ExportParameters(true).Exponent;



    //Their code ( I assume , If they only want MyModulus)
    var rsa2 =   new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024);
    var rsa2Params = rsa2.ExportParameters(true);
    rsa2Params.Modulus=MyModulus;  //they set their Modulus to MY Modulus
    rsa2Params.Exponent=MyExponent;  //they set their Modulus to MY Modulus
    byte[] enc_data = rsa2.Encrypt(data_clear, true);



   // Back to my code
    var g=Encoding.UTF8.GetString( rsa.Decrypt(enc_data, true));
    Console.WriteLine(g); 

   //CryptographicException Error occurred while decoding OAEP padding.
```

Comment: I would think they need the modulus and the exponent. Something seems pretty dodgy here.

Comment: @EricLippert Hello Eric. Even if I supply the exponent , [it failes](https://i.imgur.com/H1uMPRG.jpg)

Comment: The Modulus kind of **is** the public part of key (private key = all factors separately), but it's useless without the exponent, isn't it?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer it is useless for them yes - but they don't need to decrypt ( it is me which should do that). I do have the private key. But that's not my question. As you can see , even If I have the private and public keys , it fails to decrypt the data ( When they use the module only).

Comment: As @EricLippert said, you need both the Modulus and the Exponent.  The reason this works is that almost all RSA keys use a fixed exponent of F4 (0x010001).  With you doing ExportParameters, overwriting Modulus and then doing ImportParameters you're just preserving the existing Exponent value, which is probably what they're doing on the receiving side.  The public-key operation is `paddedMessage^Exponent % Modulus`, so Exponent is most certainly required :).

Comment: @bartonjs I didn't know about that default value. Thanks

Comment: @bartonjs If so , why didn't it work [_when I also supplied exponent_](https://i.imgur.com/H1uMPRG.jpg)?

Comment: Because RSAParameters is an export/import structure, it never changes an existing key object unless you call ImportParameters.

Comment: @bartonjs Isn't it dangerous that they rely on that default 65537 (commonly used) exponent ? I mean MS can change that in one of their SP updates. no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Here is the thing.

It seems that setting the new value in  the last line in:

```
var rsa2 =   new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);  
var rsa2Params = rsa2.ExportParameters(false);
rsa2Params.Modulus=MyModulus; //they set their Modulus to MY Modulus
```

, wasn't really visible to the  `rsa2` object becuase RSAParameters is a struct.

So we need `rsa2` to **import** that structure.

I added this line:

```
rsa2.ImportParameters(rsa2Params);
```

Also - an Exponent is surely needed. so how come it can work on their side without me to provide them the exponent ? well , this is becuase the default value for the exponent in the today's world (0x010001). So that is the reason why they can encrypt

Anyway now it all works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1) The Modulus and Exponent are necessary for encryption. Also, used to find the corresponding private key for decryption.

2) You have not set the private key in RSACryptoServiceProvider so that you can not decrypt the byte array.

Comment: Regarding 2, the private key in my side does exists . On their side , it doesnt . They only need to encrypt

Comment: Please check your private key contents, if you are using the correct private key, the modulus and exponent of private key should be same as your public key.

Comment: They are. I know. I just didn't know about the default value of the exponent ( which I didn't supply to them). , and so didn't understand how can they encrypt without the exp part.